# How would I go about adding custom header images per category?

Tags: categories, customization, header-image

I am using WooCommerce along with the Neighborhood theme. I am trying to figure it out but I need some guidance if anyone can offer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by adding some code or by installing a plugin.

You can add the following code inside your loop:

```
if (in_category('news')) {
    get_header('news');
} else {
    get_header();
}
```

This code checks if the current post belongs to a category that's called news, and if that's true, then it will use header-news.php instead of header.php. 
You will have to create header-news.php inside your theme and add your custom header image in it.

Or you can install the following plugin which allows you to add a custom header to pages, posts, categories, or tags:

[Unique Headers](http://wordpress.org/plugins/unique-headers/)

Comment: The plugin direction would be nice as the client could update them... I just do not see how to add images to woocommerce product categories...I see no option for regular cats either.